# QGIS Midvatten database error (python error while executing python code)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, midvatten

I am trying to create a Midvatten database and i keep getting error message that says "error has occured while executing python code (python error)". 
Below is the error message:
2016-08-09T18:28:49 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/agustus/.qgis2/python/plugins\midvatten\midvatten.py", line 654, in new_db
                newdbinstance = newdb(verno)
              File "C:\Users\agustus.qgis2\python\plugins\midvatten\tools\create_db.py", line 35, in **init**
                self.create_new_db(verno,user_select_CRS,EPSG_code)#CreateNewDB(verno)
              File "C:\Users\agustus.qgis2\python\plugins\midvatten\tools\create_db.py", line 78, in create_new_db
                self.rs = self.cur.execute(line.replace('CHANGETORELEVANTEPSGID',str(EPSGID)).replace('CHANGETOPLUGINVERSION',str(verno)).replace('CHANGETOQGISVERSION',str(qgisverno)).replace('CHANGETOSPLITEVERSION',str(versionstext[0][0]))) # use tags to find and replace SRID and versioning info
            UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf8' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)

2016-08-09T18:45:19 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/agustus/.qgis2/python/plugins\midvatten\midvatten.py", line 654, in new_db
                newdbinstance = newdb(verno)
              File "C:\Users\agustus.qgis2\python\plugins\midvatten\tools\create_db.py", line 35, in **init**
                self.create_new_db(verno,user_select_CRS,EPSG_code)#CreateNewDB(verno)
              File "C:\Users\agustus.qgis2\python\plugins\midvatten\tools\create_db.py", line 78, in create_new_db
                self.rs = self.cur.execute(line.replace('CHANGETORELEVANTEPSGID',str(EPSGID)).replace('CHANGETOPLUGINVERSION',str(verno)).replace('CHANGETOQGISVERSION',str(qgisverno)).replace('CHANGETOSPLITEVERSION',str(versionstext[0][0]))) # use tags to find and replace SRID and versioning info
            UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf8' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)

i do have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using QGIS 2.16 'Nødebo'? If so, you may have encountered [this bug](https://github.com/jkall/qgis-midvatten-plugin/issues/158).

The bug has been fixed and for Midvatten plugin users, now there are three alternatives:

1. keep using qgis 2.14 until we release next version of midvatten
   plugin including this bug fix
2. work with the development version of midvatten plugin from this [this git repository](https://github.com/jkall/qgis-midvatten-plugin) (not really recommended since we are
   working on some major database design changes)
3. minor fix of your own midvatten plugin installation: open the file "create_db.py" and replace "str(qgisverno)" with "qgisverno" on
   line 78